# Microsoft graph API - unable to use $filter operation in "toRecipients" array

Tags: filter, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Hello guys hope ur doing good,
I want to filter out the graph api response based on the "toRecipient" which is a array, hence I used lambda expression, but it gives error.

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
    "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-09-22T06:04:17",
        "request-id": "c6077cd4-dbec-4671-9c11-10e547917d29",
        "client-request-id": "66dfbc92-2482-11f3-86f9-22652a4e4e00"
    }
}
```

My actual response is

```
            "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "abc",
                    "address": "abc@abc.com"
                }
            }
        ],
```

I had used this operation to filter out

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/sentItems/messages?&$top=1000&$search="abc@abc.com"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/sentItems/messages?&$top=1000&$search=%22abc@abc.com%22)

Answer (score 1):

Graph API calls underlaying Office 365 API.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#message), property `ToRecipients` is not filterable.